# Mule - Multiple database calls into one json

Tags: json, mule

I have a use case where I need to make several calls to different databases and then combine the results into one json object to return to the application.  What is the best way to do that in Mule?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way, but the simplest way that I will do for this purpose:

- Inbound Endpoint
- Scatter-Gather consist of several Database connectors
- Combine Collections
- DataWeave
- Outbound Endpoint